# C3 - Create and download ZIP file with Excel workbook

Tags: c#, zip

I am generating XLS files on the Server. Then I am zipping them up and streaming the ZIP back.
Here is  code:

```
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipFile, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
   // ZIP file is created here
}
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(zipPath));
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

The ZIP is created and downloaded successfully. When I try opening Excel file from the zip I am getting this:
[image]

After saying Yes it will open fine.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is not related to this code, how do you create the XLS files?

Comment: It's a long story. I use SSRS report that I export into Excel. The format is xls. These Excel files when the ZIP is downloaded by the Browser are opened with no problem.